Hightlighting String from substring
In excel, how do I highlight parts of a string in column A, based on substring(s) from column B?
The substrings in column B can be in any order, not necessarily follow the order of string from column A
For example:




String
Word




I like dog.
dog


I like cat.
cat


Parrot, cat, dog
Parrot, dog


Mouse, bird, dog
bird


soccer, football, baseball
baseball, soccer




Does this answer your question? How to find and replace part of a cell with formatted text

This will loop through the cells and compare the two strings, splitting any comma delimited lists in B into an array and comparing the elements to A.
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lr As Long
    
    Dim wordarr As Variant
    Dim element As Variant
    Dim target As Long
    
    With Sheets(1)
        lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 2 To lr
            wordarr = Split(.Cells(i, 2).Value, ",")
            For Each element In wordarr
                target = InStr(1, .Cells(i, 1).Value, element)
                If target > 0 Then
                    .Cells(i, 1).Characters(target, Len(element)).Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                End If
            Next
        Next i
    End With

